# Completely .NET ZerConf Implementation for XNA

Tags: c#, .net, xna, zeroconf

I came across Mono.ZerConf, but from what I can tell it still relies on mDNSResponder on Windows and Avahi on Linux.

But I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to implement on the XBOX 360 / XNA, but I obviously can't run mDNSResponder on the 360, though if there was an implementation that was completely in .NET I may be able to get it to work.

Are there any implementations that are completely in .NET, preferably C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this won't work because on XBox, you don't have any networking libraries available to you other than XBox Live APIs

Comment: Really?  There's no way to even do local network communication?  i.e. interact with a custom server running on my home network?  I though I've seen stuff like that before...

Comment: Well, I suppose I should clarify for the technically minded.  If you're using XNA and publishing a game on the XBox Live Indie Games Channel, no, they explicitly limit your connectivity and the APIs that you have available to you so that you cannot make any connections outside of the XBox Live network.

*If* you are able to secure a contract to make a fully featured XBox Live Arcade game, then there *might* be some facilities to do so, but that's just speculation as anyone who has such a contract also has an NDA :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize that XNA was limited like that.

Comment: It's not XNA that's limited per se.  It's the XBox platform.  To be fair, I believe there are even limits to what you can do from a communication standpoint even if you are a AAA title.  I'll give you an example, I believe that a few years ago, EA had to do some pretty heavy negotiation in order to let them host their own xbox live servers, which is why a lot of the EA Sports games were not online right away when it launched.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, there are zero limitations to what you can do in an XNA game if you publish on windows :-)